# Create a DataFrame from a dictionary with partially same values

Tags: pandas, dictionary

I'm using a function to create a dictionary with keys and values. Some values are  unique and others don't. Actually I want to use all unique values as index and keys as column names, if the key:value pair exists, fill an "x" in this cell.

Pseudo-Code:

```
def some_function():
   dict = create a dictionary
   print(dict)
   dataframe = create_Dataframe
   print(data_frame)

out:
{k1: [1,2,3,4], k2: [2,3,5,6]}

     k1    k2 
1    x     NaN   
2    x     x 
3    x     x   
4    x     Nan   
5    NaN   x
6    NaN   x
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Trick is to create a dictionary with keys as tuples of `(i, j)` where `i` values will end up in the index and `j` values will end up in the columns.  `pd.Series` constructor will make a `pd.MultiIndex` from the tuples with `i` in the first level and `j` in the second level.  When we `unstack` all will be in the right place.

#### Matching OP output

```
pd.Series({(v, k): 'x' for k in out for v in out[k]}).unstack()

    k1   k2
1    x  NaN
2    x    x
3    x    x
4    x  NaN
5  NaN    x
6  NaN    x
```

---

#### ones and zeros (more reasonable, imo)

```
pd.Series({(v, k): 1 for k in out for v in out[k]}).unstack(fill_value=0)

   k1  k2
1   1   0
2   1   1
3   1   1
4   1   0
5   0   1
6   0   1
```

---

#### Setup

```
out = {'k1': [1,2,3,4], 'k2': [2,3,5,6]}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a straightforward solution, you can use:

### Creating a dict

```
my_dict = {"k1": [1,2,3,4], "k2": [2,3,5,6]}
```

### Creating an empty dataframe

```
import itertools

idxs = sorted(list(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(my_dict.values()))))
cols = list(my_dict.keys())

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, index=idxs)
```

The result so far is:

```
print(df)

    k1   k2
1  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN
6  NaN  NaN
```

### Filling with "x"

```
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    df[k][v] = "x"
```

The result will be:

```
print(df)

    k1   k2
1    x  NaN
2    x    x
3    x    x
4    x  NaN
5  NaN    x
6  NaN    x
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply Paulo. I found a solution by myself:

dict_e = {'k':[1,2,4,6], 'l':[1,3,4,5]}

index = sorted({x for v in dict_e.values() for x in v})
columns = list(dict_e.keys())

list1 = list(map(lambda x: x in dict_e['k'], index))
list2 = list(map(lambda x: x in val2, index))


data = list(zip(liste1, liste2))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = index, columns = columns)

But since yours is easier to understand, I'll just it!